# Polymorphic association form tag_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, polymorphic-associations

With the code:

```
<div class="field">
<%= form_for [@tagable, Tag.new] do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Tag %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    <p>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create Product", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    </div>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

I've defined at my Tag model the method:

```
def tag_list
 tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(tags_string)

    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    logger.debug "#{tag_names}\n\n\n\n\n\n"

    tag_names.each do |tag_name|
      #tag = Tag.find_or_initialize_by_name(tag_name)
      #tag.save
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name)

      logger.debug "#{tag}\n\n\n\n\n\n"

    end
 end
```

The line of code at "find_or_create...." doesn't work, at the console it seems to work, but finally the code brings a name attribute nil. Like this:

```
  INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "name", "tagable_id", "tagable_type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 19 Oct 2012 01:04:31 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["tagable_id", 19], ["tagable_type", "Product"], ["updated_at", Fri, 19 Oct 2012 01:04:31 UTC +00:00]]
```

Before that code I've print at the console the content of the "tag" that I'would like to save:

```
Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'musica' LIMIT 1
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  (0.1ms)  commit transaction
```

How can I create each tag of the "tag_list"?
PS: I've also tried the comment code at the "Tag Model"

Comment: are you using any plugin for this tagging facility?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandings, you are showing a `text field` to add tags to any `taggable`. And this text field may contain list of tags (being referred as `tag_list`). And after submitting the form, that `taggable` will be associated with those tags.

If this is the case, you can try this [**`acts_as_taggable` plugin**](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)  which provides your desired `tag_list` function by default :) with rich set of options.

Some Reference Links

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702224/1160106
- [Stackoverflow posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=acts_as_taggable+%5Bruby-on-rails-3%5D)

Let me know if ive missed any of your requirements.

Comment: hmmm, the problem is that I'm making my own tagging system, I'm using polymorphic association, that's why I dont want to use the acts_as_taggable gem, I've reviewed several tutorial and the have two models, for example: product model and tag model, so they can do something like this in the product's model: def tag_list self.product.tags = collect....etc, but I would like to make something like that at the tag model, I would like to define a tag_list method inside my tag model!